LinkedIn not displaying correct meta title and meta description for ASP.NET website
I have an ASP.NET website with separate meta title and meta description tags. These tags display the correct title and description on all websites except LinkedIn. Despite following the Open Graph protocol, LinkedIn seems to be ignoring or misinterpreting these meta tags. I'm seeking guidance on how to ensure that LinkedIn displays the correct meta title and meta description for my ASP.NET website. Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.
meta data on pagesource
meta data on LinkedIn URL preview
I attempted to resolve the issue by adding the "og:title" and "og:description"
properties to the meta tag, but unfortunately, this did not alleviate the problem.
Thanks in advance.

It is possible that LinkedIn caches the data, so it may take some time to see the changes. To overcome this, you could try a different URL, preferably unknown to LinkedIn and see there how the data are retrieved.

Hello Tasos K, thank you for your response. I attempted to clear the cache, but I am still encountering the same issue. Additionally, I checked the LinkedIn Post Inspector page, and it is still displaying the incorrect meta title and description.
